# Excel PowerPivot - Cubevalue or Cubeset with condition / Filter

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Good Day , Please can I get some help with the following

I have the following `cubevalue` formula which counts the distinct suppliers in an area

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Query1].[SOURCING SPLIT].[All].[LOCAL]","[Query1].[SOURCING REPORTING PRODUCT].[All].[KNITWEAR]","[Query1].[Gender].[All]","[Measures].[distinct count of Supplier Name]")
```

The above formula returns an answer = 5

I would like to filter and have a distinct count of only the suppliers where season orders were Greater than 0, the answer should then be 2
the measure for the season's orders is: `[Measures].[sum of S’22 units]`
so I would like to add to the formula and filter  . . . `[Measures].[sum of S’22 units]>0` -- Hope this makes sense

I have also tried with Cubeset
The following formula returns 5 in the cubesetcount and should return 3 after applying a filter

```
=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","([Query1].[SOURCING SPLIT].[All].[LOCAL],[Query1].[SOURCING REPORTING PRODUCT].[All].[KNITWEAR],NONEMPTY([Measures].[sum of S'22 Units]))*[TFG Supplier Name].children","DSups")
```

I want to add a filter here so that it only applies where Units for the supplier were > 0   . . .  so I would like to add to the formula and filter  . . . `[Measures].[sum of S’22 units]>0` -- Hope this makes sense

I am stumped as to how to apply this condition and would appreciate any help please

Comment: It would be simpler to define the required measure within Power Pivot, which can then be returned quite simply using `CUBEVALUE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  . . . Would that be using something like " Calculate " in PowerPivot ?

Comment: Yes, something 
`MyMeasure:=VAR T1=SUMMARIZE(MyTable,MyTable[Supplier Name],"Sum",SUM(MyTable[S’22 units]))
RETURN SUMX(T1,0+([Sum]>0))`

Comment: Thanks very Much Jos . . . I will go that way